# Creating Dictionary from Pandas DataFrame Column Based on Unique Values in Column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, dataframe

I've got a head-scratcher that I'm not sure can be solved in one or two lines of code, which I'm trying. I can more or less do it without a dataframe (e.g., if the data is simply .txt), but I want to see if it can be done with pandas.

Below is the `df.head(10)`, and I want to create a dictionary in which the **keys** are the parsed unique `day_of_week` numericals (1-7, for Sunday-Saturday) and the **values** are the ***sum*** of the `births` that occur on each of the individual `day_of_week` values.

```
    year    month   date_of_month   day_of_week births
  0 1994      1          1              6        8096
  1 1994      1          2              7        7772
  2 1994      1          3              1        10142
  3 1994      1          4              2        11248
  4 1994      1          5              3        11053
  5 1994      1          6              4        11406
  6 1994      1          7              5        11251
  7 1994      1          8              6        8653
  8 1994      1          9              7        7910
  9 1994      1          10             1        10498
```

I can create the SUM for respective `day_of_week` values easily with:

```
df.groupby[df['day_of_week'] == 1, 'births'].sum()
```

which sums all the births that occur on `day_of_week == 1`. And I can create a dictionary of the `day_of_week` values with:

```
d = {i : 0 for i in df['day_of_week']}
```

which yeilds a dictionary, `d`:

```
{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0}
```

But I cannot connect the two so that I can parse the `day_of_week` numbers, assign those numbers to the **key** of a dictionary, then sum the `births` that occur on each respective `day_of_week`, then assign those sum values to their respective keys.

If anyone has suggestions! I've created a dummy dataframe below that replicates the conditions, if that helps, since the `day_of_week` values do repeat in my dataframe (though you can't tell from `df.head()`).

```
d = {'day_of_week' : pd.Series([1, 6, 6, 5, 3, 2, 6, 4, 4, 7, 1]),
    'births' : pd.Series([5544, 23456, 473, 34885, 3498, 324, 6898, 83845, 959, 8923, 39577])}
df_dummy = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: Apologies, I meant to write: `df.groupby('day_of_week')['births'].sum()[1]` for the code that sums all the `births` that occur on `day_of_week` == 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need

```
df_dummy.set_index('day_of_week').births.sum(level=0).to_dict()
Out[30]: {1: 45121, 2: 324, 3: 3498, 4: 84804, 5: 34885, 6: 30827, 7: 8923}
```

Comment: @RichardS yw : -) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

This can definitely be answered in one line with pandas. Simply use the groupby construct to groupby your parsed day of week and then sum the number of births. Pandas has built in functionality to turn this into a dictionary, where your keys are the day of the week and the values are the sum:

```
import pandas as pd
day_of_week = [6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1]
births = [8096, 7772, 10142, 11248, 11053, 11406, 11251, 8653, 7910, 10498]

df = pd.DataFrame({'day_of_week': day_of_week,
               'births': births})

df.groupby('day_of_week')['births'].sum().to_dict()
# output: {1: 20640, 2: 11248, 3: 11053, 4: 11406, 5: 11251, 6: 16749, 7: 15682}
```